# How to filter result with certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables and I want to filter certain criteria.

> Table 1
>   Student
>   ID Name
>    1 Del
>   2 Mark
>   3 Dave
>
> Table 2
>   Requirements
>   ID Stud_id Requirement isSubmitted
>   1----1--------Req1-------------1
>   2----1--------Req2-------------0
>   3----2--------Req1-------------1
>   4----2--------Req2-------------1
>   5----3--------Req1-------------0
>   6----3--------Req2-------------0

I need to filter out the students who have completed the requirements, and those who have incomplete requirements.

> Output 1:Students with completed requirements.
>    ID Name
>   2 Mark
>
> ---
>
> Output 2: Students with incomplete requirements.
>   ID Name
>   1 Del
>   3 Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `exists` and `not exists`.  For completed requirements:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from requirements r
                  where r.stud_id = s.id and r.isSubmitted = 0
                 );
```

For incompleted, use `exists` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

For retrieving students who completed the requirements:

```
select * from student s where s.ID in ((Select stud_id from requirements r 
where r.req1=1 and r.req2=1))
```

For retrieving students who have incomplete requirements:

```
select * from student s where s.ID not in ((Select stud_id from requirements r 
where r.req1=1 and r.req2=1))
```